# Check if element is in a model - Django templates

Tags: python, html, django, templates, model

i'm trying to make a like button. And everything works fine except for the fact that i can't check (inside the template) if something is already liked by the user. In other words, i can't check for an existing row in the database.

Im trying this for the template:
If the user likes the post. That post shows a filled heart, otherwise it shows only a heart contour

```
{% for post in posts %}
   {% if post in likelist %}
      <i class="fa fa-heart like" data-id="{{ post.id }}" id="like-{{ post.id }}" style="color:red;"></i>
   {% else %}
      <i class="fa fa-heart-o like" data-id="{{ post.id }}" id="like-{{ post.id }}" style="color:red;"> 
   </i>
   {% endif %} 
{% endfor %}
```

But the if statement is giving always False, even when the user actually likes the post.

Here is the model:

```
class Likelist(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('User', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='liker')
    likes = models.ForeignKey('Posts', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='likes')

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.user} likes {self.likes}"
```

And i'm passing the context in views.py through render

```
return render(request, "network/profile.html", {
      #[...]some other contexts
      "posts": Posts.objects.filter(user=user_id).order_by('-timestamp'), 
      "likelist": Likelist.objects.filter(user=request.user),
    })
```

If i try to print it in a HTML tag ( {{likelist}} or {{posts}} ) the querysets appears so the context is passing fine.
I don't know why the conditional isn't checking the existence of the element in the database

Comment: `likelist` is a set of `Likelist` objects, `post` is `Post` object, so a `Post` object can never be in `likelist`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`likelist` is a collection of *`Likelist`* objects, `post` is `Post` object, so a `Post` object can never be in `likelist`.

But even if it was, it is not a good idea to check membership like that, since it will make an extra query for each `Post` object. You can annotate the `Post`s and check if these are liked with an [**`Exists`** subquery [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/expressions/#exists-subqueries):

```
from django.db.models import Exists, OuterRef

posts = Posts.objects.filter(
    user=user_id
).annotate(
    is_liked=Exists(Likedlist.objects.filter(
        likes=OuteRef('pk'), user=user_id
    ))
).order_by('-timestamp')

return render(request, 'network/profile.html', {
    'posts': posts,
})
```

Then in the template, you check with:

```
{% for post in posts %}
   {% if post.is_liked %}
      …
   {% else %}
      …
   {% endif %} 
{% endfor %}
```

---

> **Note**: normally a Django model is given a *singular* name, so `Post` instead of <s>`Posts`</s>.